# 'Tagging' records based on dynamic attributes, and filters from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an a `Groups` table with an array of JSON objects representing different filters to be applied to a SQL query

Example `group`:

```
id: 1,
name: "my group",
filters: [
  {field: "sessions", type: "greater_than", value: 5}, 
  {field: "email", type: "contains", value: "@example.com}
]
```

An example record of the filtered table `Visitors`

```
id: 1, email: "example@gmail.com", sessions: 5, more_meta_data..
```

What I'd like to get is something like:

```
id: 1, matching_groups: ["my group"], email: "example@gmail.com", sessions: 5  more_meta_data..
```

Note that a visitor can be in many groups at the same time.

When querying a `Visitor`, I'd like to append the name of all the `Groups` for which all the filters match the attributes on the `Visitior` record.

I am kind of lost on this one, and apologise if I haven't explained it clearly enough. Does Postgres allow for this to be done at the DB level?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks

Comment: What version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: Consider migrating to 9.5. First, 9.4 is a preview version and therefore some libraries might not fully support it. Second, the support for JSON has improved a lot from 9.4 to 9.5.

Comment: Is it really worth it to implement all this filtering logic in SQL? I don't know your exact setup, but you might be duplicating a lot of your business logic that you also need to implement in another language. If so, you might be better off implementing an SQL generator that uses your configured group filters as metadata.

Comment: Well I thought of doing it in SQL purely for performance reasons. I imagine that if I did in at the application layer, i'd have to perform a seperate query for each of the groups, and then keep track of which returns the `visitor` in question.

Comment: This just seems inefficient, as it's possible that a user has created 20+ groups, ie. 20 queries must be performed (atleast with my approach)

Comment: Remember to first do it, then do it right, then do it fast. – As long as you don't have many thousands of users to query against, performance will most likely not be an issue. Improving your approach in a way that allows you to load all groups with a single query and/or cache the loaded groups might be easier than implementing all the filtering logic in SQL. I also imagine debugging your logic will be easier if implemented outside SQL. I might be a bit biased, though (coming from a Ruby on Rails background). If you end up with a nice SQL based solution, let me know! :)