# Conditional WHERE expression in dynamic query

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION match_custom_filter(filters text[], id text)
        RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$
        DECLARE
            r boolean;
        BEGIN
            execute format(
                'SELECT 1 FROM trackings t LEFT JOIN visitors v ON v.id = t.visitor_id
                WHERE v.id = ''%s'' AND %s',
                id,
                array_to_string(filters, ') AND ('))
            into r;
            RETURN r;
        END $$;

select v.*, array_agg(g.name) as groups from visitors v join groups g on match_custom_filter(g.formatted_custom_filters, v.id)
where v.id = 'cov4pisw00000sjctfyvwq126'
group by v.id
```

This works fine when the filters are not empty. But it is also possible that a filter is empty, in which case I will have an dangling AND with no right hand side.

Error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 2: ...               WHERE v.id = 'cov4pisw00000sjctfyvwq126' AND 
                                                                       ^
QUERY:  SELECT 1 FROM trackings t LEFT JOIN visitors v ON v.id = t.visitor_id
                WHERE v.id = 'cov4pisw00000sjctfyvwq126' AND 
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function match_custom_filter(text[],text) line 5 at EXECUTE statement
```

What's the best way to handle this?

UPDATE:

Example of how I generate the array of string filters based off JSONB array of filter objects

```
def build_condition(%{"filter" => filter, "field" => field, "value" => value}) when field in @default_values do
    case filter do
      "greater_than"      -> "#{field} > #{value}"
      "less_than"         -> "#{field} < #{value}"
      "is"                -> "#{field} = '#{value}'"
      "is_not"            -> "#{field} <> '#{value}'" 
      ..
```

Comment: Can the filter use any operator or is it just equality?

Comment: When you say "empty" do you mean the empty string `''`, `NULL` or either?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto operators like these: `#{field} > #{value}`, `"#{field} ILIKE '#{value}' || '%'"` and `"#{field} < NOW() - (#{value} || ' days')::interval"`

Comment: @Patrick My bad, I mean than the filter array is empty as in an empty list

Answer (score 4):

First, a warning.  What you are doing here gives you in-stored-proc sql injection.  I highly recommend you reconsider so you can properly parameterize.

Now, having said this, the obvious option is to declare a text variable and then pre-process it.

In your `DECLARE` block you add:

```
 filterstring text;
```

then in your body, you add:

```
 filterstring := array_to_string(filters, ') AND ('))
 IF filterstring = '' or filterstring is null THEN
     filterstring := 'TRUE';
 END IF;
```

Then you use `filterstring` in place of the `array_to_string` call in the `format()` call.

Note that any time you assemble a query anywhere by string interpolation you have the possibility of sql injection.

To protect against SQL injection you will need to rethink your approach a little bit.  Your best option is not to use format() for your query to the extent possible.  So:

```
execute 'SELECT 1 FROM trackings t 
      LEFT JOIN visitors v ON v.id = t.visitor_id
          WHERE v.id = $1'
   USING id;
```

That causes planning and filling in the value to happen on two different points.  That works well in the case of a simple parameter.  However it doesn't work well in the case of the dynamic filters.

Instead of passing a one-dimensional array in, you could pass a two dimensional (nx3 array) with three elements per line.  These would be column name, operator, and value.  You can sanitize the column name by passing it through `quote_ident` and the value by passing it through `quote_literal` but sanitizing the operators is likely to be a problem so my recommendation would be to whitelist these and throw an exception if the operator is not found.  Something like:

```
  DECLARE 
          ...
          op TEXT;
          allowed_ops TEXT[] := ARRAY['=', '<=', '>='];
  BEGIN
       ...
       IF not(op = ANY(allowed_ops)) THEN
           RAISE EXCEPTION 'Illegal operator in function, %', op;
       END IF;
       ...
  END;
```

This is not going to be easy but it is doable.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I am still very new to DBs. I was under the impression that stored procedures protected against SQL injection. What steps would I have to take to secure it properly while still being able to create dynamic queries?

Comment: added that info.  Not trivial in your case to protect yourself but hopefully the pointers help.

Comment: Actually, I already keep a JSONB array of filter objects exactly as you describe. I just also maintain them in a 'concatenated' form as was suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844930/tagging-records-based-on-dynamic-attributes-and-filters-from-another-table. In this case, would I still be vulnerable to SQL injection, as the mapping of JSON object to `field relation value` is done in a controlled manner. Updated the post with an example

Comment: If all your filters will be stored in the table, you can hand-verify that they don't do anything funny and then check to make sure every filter is in the table before interpolating them.  That may be the easiest way.  (I.e. make sure tehre are no filters NOT IN (select filtercond from filtertable).

Comment: ALL the filters are not hardcoded in the database, but I have that function that maps a {relation, field, value} object to a string using interpolation, so that relation is 'filtered'. However, I guess it would still be possible for an attacker to exploit the interpolated `field` or `value`, yeah?

Comment: if you run `quote_ident(field)` and `quote_literal(value)` those will be safely escaped in the output of those functions.  I think you still have to whitelist operators.  If field names are fully qualified you need to run `quote_ident(table) || '.' || quote_ident(field)` however

Comment: Since I control the the operators in my mapping, is this still needed? What exactly is meant by a fully qualified field?

Comment: Controlling the operators is a form of whitelisting too and is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have your [filters in the form of a `jsonb` array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37844930/3304426) to begin with, you should use that as a function parameter instead of a `text[]`. For one thing, it will allow you to protect against SQL-injection.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION match_custom_filter(filters jsonb, id text)
RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    f text;
    r boolean;
BEGIN
    IF jsonb_array_length(filters) = 0 THEN
        -- If no filters are specified then run a straight SQL query against trackings
        PERFORM * FROM trackings WHERE visitor_id = quote_literal(id);
        RETURN FOUND;
    ELSE
        -- Build the filters from the jsonb array
        SELECT string_agg(
                   -- Concatenate the parts from a single json object into a filter
                   quote_ident(j->>'field') ||    -- avoid SQL injection on column name
                   CASE j->>'type'
                       WHEN 'greater_than' THEN ' > '
                       ...
                   END ||
                   quote_literal(j->>'value'),    -- avoid SQL injection on value

                   -- Aggregate individual filters with the AND operator
                   ' AND ') INTO f
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(filters) j;

        -- Run a dynamic query with the filters
        EXECUTE format('SELECT true FROM trackings t 
                        LEFT JOIN visitors v ON v.id = t.visitor_id
                        WHERE v.id = %L AND %s LIMIT 1', id, f) INTO r;
        RETURN r;
    END IF;
END $$;
```

You should call this function passing in the `jsonb` array, like so:

```
SELECT v.*, array_agg(g.name) AS groups
FROM visitors v JOIN groups g ON match_custom_filter(g.group->'filter', v.id)
WHERE v.id = 'cov4pisw00000sjctfyvwq126'
GROUP BY v.id;
```

Comment: Hey, I can use the JSONB array of filter objects, no problem. I only chose this approach because it was recommended with regards to simplicity and performance. Could you give an example of how to solve it using the JSON objects instead, thus eliminating the SQL injection?